# Karma Unit test does not works well for the component function?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

This is my component function

```
 this.cocmenuitems=[];
  LoadMenus() {
        this.cocmenuitems.push({ label: 'Search'});
    }
```

Unit testing method

```
   beforeEach(() => {
        this.modalNota = new AppComponent();
    });
   it('Should test LoadMenus method', () => {
        this.modalNota.LoadMenus();//component method executed well
        alert(12);// but this alert does not fire and the result is shown failed status
        expect(this.modalNota.cocmenuitems[0].label).toBe('Search');
    });
```

This `this.modalNota.LoadMenus()` execution is working good, because `this.cocmenuitems` having value while am check it in console window. But the next line `alert(12)` does not executed. Why?

Comment: can you share a plunker for the same .

Comment: Thr have lot of code need to add in plunkr. So I couldn't update my code in plunkr. sorry. But i'll be clarify anything here